# PhoneGap build app running slow on android device but not in emulator

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

Im making an app using phonegap and when I test the app on my phone it takes about a second or two for things to happen when I press a button or slide out my sliding panel, this all works perfectly fine and fast in Ripple Emulator just fine. I have already tried adding

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion"   value="14" />
```

to my config.xml file but that didn't do anything. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on your design framework. if you are using Jquery-mobile, apps will be little slow on device.

Comment: Yeah, it uses jQuery mobile for pretty much everything. Is there any way to make it faster if that's the problem? Because if there isn't I'm gonna have to remake the entire thing.

Comment: Just to make this clear, the app will be for android and iphone or just android?

Comment: Android, iphone and windows phone

Comment: If you want to do it with minimum alterations, have a look at jquery mobile v 2.0. It is alight faster than previous versions. Secondly i will recommend some better ui frameworks like sencha and intel is also have their design framework.Have a look at them.